# Prove or disprove limits

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics

Let $f$ be defined in a deleted neighborhood of $U$ of $x_0 = 0$.
$f$ is differentiable and has a vertical asymptote at $x = 0$
then at least one of the limits $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0^+} f'(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0^-} f'(x)$
exists, when they tends to infinity.

I think this statement is correct. if the limits were of $f(x)$ instead of $f'(x)$ then it was immediate by definition of an asymptote. my direction: I want to prove in contradiction that f converges and hopefully something will go wrong there. I'd like to get some help with that or another direction is good as well

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $f$ is defined in a neighbourhood of $x = 0$, then isn't $f$ also defined at $x = 0$? How can $f$ then have a vertical asymptote at $x = 0$?

Comment: @KennyWong I edited my question (it is defined but in 0) (0-epsilon, 0)U(0, 0+epsilon)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not true. For example, you can define a function which is differentiable for $x\neq 0$, increasing and tending to $+\infty$ as $x\to 0^+$ and decreasing to $-\infty$ as $x\to 0^-$, such that $f(1/n)=n$ and $f'(1/n)=0$ for every integer $n$. To do this, for each interval $(1/(n+1),1/n)$ you can choose a cubic equation with the required values and derivatives at $x=1/(n+1)$ and $x=1/n$, then just define $f(x)$ for $x\in(1/(n+1),1/n)$ to be the value of that cubic evaluated at $x$.